# Getting undefined in alert box for AngularJS scope variable

Tags: angularjs, undefined

The following is the selection list:

`<select ng-Change="getSubTaskList(editTransferButtonData.selectedFirstHeader)" ng-model="editTransferButtonData.selectedFirstHeader" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Header</option>
<option ng-repeat="header in selectProjectTaskDetails" value="{{header}}" ng-selected="editTransferButtonData.fromHeaderId === header.headerId">{{header.name}}</option></select>`

When I try to retrieve `undefined` message is displayed.

```
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.editTransferButtonData.selectedFirstHeader));
```

can any one help me to identify why it's returning `undefined`.

Comment: `ng-Change` should be `ng-change`

Comment: Simply because $scope.editTransferButtonData.selectedFirstHeader is undefined. If you want more help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, and explain clearly what you're doing. Also, learn to use ng-options. Generating options using ng-repeat is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

it should be,

```
<select ng-change="getSubTaskList(editTransferButtonData.selectedFirstHeader)" ng-model="editTransferButtonData.selectedFirstHeader" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Header</option>
<option ng-repeat="header in selectProjectTaskDetails" value="{{header}}" ng-selected="editTransferButtonData.fromHeaderId === header.headerId">{{header.name}}</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem because of **JSON mismatch**, `ng-model="editTransferButtonData.selectedFirstHeader"` is different from `value="{{header}}"` which is returning.